# htaccess - rewritecond to check for slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a rewriterule on my site thats like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ open.php?url=$1 [L]
```

(There is a lot above it but this is the last rule)

It works very nicely.

What I want to achieve, however, is that if the url is as follows:

```
http://site.com/first/second
```

Then I want to redirect to

```
open.php?url=$1&open=$2
```

The problem is that I want to have both of them at the same time so that site.com/foo works as well as site.com/foo/bar . I also want to avoid having a trailing slash there all the time ergo both of the rules at the same time.

If there a way to check for trailing slashes with a rewritecond of some sort

any help is appreciated :)

### SOLVED

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ open.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ open.php?url=$1&open=$2 [L]
```

All I had to add was a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)/(.*)$` on the first rule!